# jQuery method is not showing up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a `<div>` that contains a table inside it and I want use the `resize` method in jQuery but it is not showing and I don't know what's the problem.
I loaded the jQuery script that contain the `resize` method but it's still not showing anything.

Here's the jQuery call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>
```

and this is how I want to use it:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    setslider($('#dynamicdata'));
});
```

I thought maybe if I put the jQuery call inside the master page it'll work but nothing happened. I used it inside another project and it work correctly but when I use it in my website methods won't show up!

Comment: Check if jquery loaded in browser. Open console (e.g. in Chrome -> Tools/JavaScript Console) and type "jQuery" without quotes, case sensitive. If you get ReferenceError it didn't load.

Comment: I used firebug and the JQuery is called correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling you function after the document finished loading, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function () {
        setslider($('#dynamicdata'));
    });
});
```

Comment: the method is showed but there's  wonder mark before their name. that said the provided list contains all identifiers in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the setslider function? You're calling that as though it were in the global window space. Is it? Is that something that needs to be loaded in another JS lib? If so, that's the problem.

Comment: I opened error console i found this error about the JQuery:            XUL box for _moz_generated_content_befor element contained an inline #text child,forcing all its children to be wrapped in a block??? what is it?